# Table grid control for ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, listview, webforms

What is the best way for me to build a control that will kinda work like an Access table in ASP.NET?

That is, I define, say, 3 columns.  The user can add/edit/remove rows.  It can be one row at a time, that's fine.  There are other fields on the form too, not related to this table.  When the user is done adding rows of information, then they hit 'submit', and at *that* point, is when I grab all the data out of the control and save to a database (or xml file or whatever).

I've tried to build something with ListView and/or GridView, and I just can't seem to get the behavior I want.  Any ideas or examples?

Comment: Which specific behaviors are you not able to implement using ListView/GridView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess what I'm looking for is kinda a hack:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/viewstate/retainingstate.aspx

But it seems to be the easiest way to what I want to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look into jQuery's [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/).

[Demo here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html). What I see in terms of grid manipulation are related to row editing, not too sure about columns though.

Related [SO Posts here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jqgrid).

Answer (score 1):

On link that could be useful:

[Using the New ListView Control in ASP.NET 3.5](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/38579)
Eksample from own project:

```
               <asp:ListView ID="lvList" runat="server" OnLayoutCreated="lvList_LayoutCreated" OnItemDataBound="lvList_OnItemDataBound">
                    <LayoutTemplate>
                        <table id="tblTest" class="lvtest" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                            <tr>
                                <th class="listheader">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server" />
                                </th>
                                <th class="listheader">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lbl2" runat="server" />
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
                        </table>
                    </LayoutTemplate>
                    <EmptyDataTemplate>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblNotFound" runat="server" OnInit="lblOnInit" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </EmptyDataTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <tr class="<%# Container.DataItemIndex % 2 == 0 ? "odd" : "even" %>">
                            <td class="listcell">
                                <asp:Literal ID="lit1" runat="server" />
                            </td>
                            <td class="listcell">
                                <asp:Literal ID="lit1" runat="server" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:ListView>
```

Event handlers:

```
    protected void lvRist_LayoutCreated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetHeaderValues();
    }


    //For the label when empty text
        protected void lblOnInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetEmptyText(sender);
    }



    protected void lvList_OnItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType != ListViewItemType.DataItem) return;

        SetDataItem(e);
    }
```

Comment: I've been trying to do that , but with ObjectDataSource wrapped around a ViewState.  I don't have a SQL database to save to, and I wouldn't want to save until user hits 'submit' anyway.